# Visual Notification given programmatically from browser window

Tags: javascript, browser

I need a way of programmatically triggering either bringing the browser window to front or at least the window flickering. I have noticed that `window.alert` does it in firefox but it doesn't in chrome. Opening a new tab (`window.open`)causes flickering in Chrome but it's not a solution - it would be if I could close the "old tab"
Is there something like "visually notify user" working at least for current versions of firefox, chrome and edge?

Comment: Have a look at the [Notification.API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

Comment: Does a [notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) work for you?